# Web project links to sql-server-ce 3.5 instead of 4.0

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm having problems with a web-project built on two machines.

The first has:

- .NET 4.0
- Sql-Server-Ce 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Sql-Server-Ce 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU
- Sql-Server-Ce 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU CTP1

In VisualStudio I include SqlServerCe as a reference, as version 4.0.0.0. If I examine the resulting dll (with ildasm or Reflector) I can see that it references the correct 4.0 version of SqlServerCe.

This code is then moved to a separate (build) machine with:

- .NET 4.0
- Sql-Server-Ce 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Sql-Server-Ce 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU
- Sql-Server-Ce 4.0 x64 ENU

and is rebuilt. This time, however, the dll is linked against the 3.5.1.0 version of SqlServerCe.
The v4.0 sql-server is slightly different on the new machine (x64 enu vs. sp1 x64 enu), but this shouldn't disrupt the build, should it?

Any ideas why the new build is refusing to link to the 4.0 version?
I'm guessing there's something really simple I'm missing, a config thing?

Comment: Use specific version = true in your reference

Comment: I will try it. Can I ask what the logic is for using that? It implies that the framework is able to choose which version to link against even though the reference is specified as 4.0 in VisualStudio. Is there something that defines which version is used?

Comment: @ErikEJ, thanks, that worked :). Problem is, I can't give your comment as the correct answer (not enough reputation points?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use specific version = true in your reference